# Input with 'em' min-width shows whitespace having same 'M' chars

Tags: css

I have an input with `min-width:30em` and `max-size` is 30 so I put 30 `M` characters in and it shows white space.

(Min-width is increasing the actual size.)

(Ignore that I used `box-sizing:border-box`, `content-box` increases the white space more.)

Watching the layout, I see that it isn't margin/padding/box-sizing related.

Tried removing the font-family and saw that the text decreases width but not the container.

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiU07.png)  [Container layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtmVr.png)

Expected the input being fully filled without white spaces.

Comment: The em-square unit does not necessarily (or even usually) correspond to the advance-width of the "M" glyph.

Comment: @Alohci so what should I use to make the `width` similar to the `maxlength`? I read that `ch` was the size of `0` and `em` was the `font-size`, being `M` similar because it was supposed to be the `max-width` character.